# WPF: Create 8x8 TextBox table in codebehind

Tags: wpf, binding, code-behind

I need to create 8x8 TextBox table, each TextBox should be bound to element of double[,] array (i want to let user change matrix from ui).

What is the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use an ItemsControl, and change the ItemPanel from the default StackPanel to a WrapPanel.  Something like:

```
<ItemsControl>
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <WrapPanel />
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        ...
      </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Cool idea! That's totally what I need. No XAML copy-paste, no dirty tricks in codebehind. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make use of a [UniformGrid](http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2009/08/02/primitives-panels-in-wpf-uniformgrid/)...

```
<UniformGrid>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
         ...
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
</UniformGrid>
```

You may need to make use of an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to deal with the way in which you are binding as well as setting the width and height to a fixed size to guarantee your 8x8 representation but the `UniformGrid` as a container should suffice to meet your goal of an 8x8 table.